# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр класса

Tags: c#

Хотел сделать класс(Box), в котором поля(name, age, length) вводились бы с form-ы, а потом находилось бы максимальное значение поля lenght и через MessageBox отправлялось бы  сообщение имени самого высокого человека.

```
     public Box(string name, int width, int length, int weight, int age) => NewPers = name;
    public int Len //как я понял, здесь я добавляю свойство, чтобы обращаться к приватному параметру length с других блоков программы 
    {
        get {
            return length;
        }
        set {
            length = value; 
        }
    }
    public string NewPers 
    {
        get => name[counter];
        set
        {
            name[counter] = value;
            
        }
    }

}                    





private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Box[] NameBox = new Box[5]; //создаю объекты класса Box
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (NameBox[i] != null) //если значение не равно нулю, то продолжаем
                continue;

            NameBox[i] = new Box(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text), int.Parse(textBox4.Text), int.Parse(textBox5.Text));
                break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= NameBox.Length; j++)
        {
            if (max < NameBox[j].Len)
            {
                max = NameBox[j].Len; 
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show( $"Максимальный рост у человека {max}");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Вообщем я позавчера решил познакомиться поближе, пока еще мало что понимаю => возможно, вообще ерунду пишу. *Не забывайте про комментарии, пожалуйста*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для простоты я ваш класс Box урезал до двух свойств (остальные там просто не использовались) будет не сложно их добавить. Во первых зачем вы каждый раз создаете массив Box[] NameBox = new Box[5]; ? цикл заполнения тоже очень странный, да и не нужный в принципе. Вообще проще использовать список, советую их изучить. Сделайте вторую кнопку "сброс" подклчите к ней обработчик button2_Click
для сброса массива.

- свойства можно объявлять без переменных(их создаст компилятор);
- для сравнения удобно использовать шаблон IComparable;
- конвертировать типы желательно через TryParse с проверкой на ошибку;
- ф-я Max() - из linq, если не знакомы очень советую изучить, это очень мощный инструмент;

  ```
   private int _curIndex;
   private Box[] _boxes = new Box[5];

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (_curIndex == _boxes.Length)
       {
           MessageBox.Show($"Массив полностью заполнен");
           return;
       }
       if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out var len))
       {
           MessageBox.Show($"Рост указан не верно");
           return;
       }

       _boxes[_curIndex] = new Box(textBox1.Text, len);
       _curIndex++;

       var maxHighBox = _boxes.Max();

       MessageBox.Show($"Максимальный рост у человека {maxHighBox.Name} - {maxHighBox.Len}");
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _curIndex = 0;
       _boxes = new Box[5];
   }

   public class Box : IComparable<Box>
   {
       public int Len { get; }

       public string Name { get; }

       public Box(string name, int len)
       {
           Len = len;
           Name = name;
       }

       public int CompareTo(Box other) => Len.CompareTo(other.Len);
   }
  ```

Comment: Мне надо сделать с массивом объектов класса, конструкторов, свойств. Я еще не изучал то, что вы пишите.

Comment: @ЛевиЙоффер ок, перделал на массив. Добавьте еще одну кнопку "сбросить" для сброса масива(для нового цикла ввода) и подключите обработчик button2_Click он есть в коде. Вам по сути остается почитать про linq и IComparable поверьте это займет совсем не много времени ))

Comment: Другой разговор)

Answer (score 2):

После создания массива **все** его элементы будут `null` - поэтому нет смысла проверять в цикле

```
NameBox[i] != null
```

это выражение всегда вернет `false`

[`break`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) - прерывает выполнение цикла. В данном случае цикл **всегда** прерывается после первой итерации.

Таким образом инициализируется всегда только нулевой элемент.

Поэтому во втором цикле попытка взять

```
NameBox[j].Len
```

у любого элемента с индексом больше 0 будет приводить к указанной ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

**Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр класса** - вы обращаетесь к объекту который не инициализирован

### вот как должно быть

По порядку сам класс

```
class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    //ctor empty
    public Human()
    {
        
    }

    //ctor with params
    public Human(string name, string width, string height, string weight, string age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Width = Convert.ToDouble(width);
        Height = Convert.ToDouble(height);
        Weight = Convert.ToDouble(weight);
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(age);
    }

    //ctor with params for textbox
    public Human(TextBox name, TextBox width, TextBox height, TextBox weight, TextBox age)
    {
        Name = name.Text;
        Width = Convert.ToDouble(width.Text);
        Height = Convert.ToDouble(height.Text);
        Weight = Convert.ToDouble(weight.Text);
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(age.Text);
    }


}
```

теперь его реализация

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Human> _humans = new List<Human>();//создаем список с нашим классом
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Human human1 = new Human("imja1", "10", "110", "10", "10");// создаем экземпляр класса
            _humans.Add(human1);//добавляем его в список 
            Human human2 = new Human("imja2", "20", "120", "20", "20");
            _humans.Add(human2);
            Human human3 = new Human("imja3", "30", "130", "30", "30");
            _humans.Add(human3);
            Human human4 = new Human("imja4", "40", "140", "40", "40");
            _humans.Add(human4);
            Human human5 = new Human("imja5", "50", "150", "50", "50");
            _humans.Add(human5);


        }

        //кнопка добавить человека в список
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Human human = new Human(textBox1,textBox2,textBox3,textBox4,textBox5);//тут указываем переменные Texbox
            _humans.Add(human);

        }
        //кнопка найти человака с самым большим ростом 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Human result = _humans.Find(x => x.Height == _humans.Max(z => z.Height));// ишем человека с саммым высоким ростом

            MessageBox.Show(result.Name);// показываем его имя
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что за TextBox-ы? мне надо переименовать их?

Comment: //ctor with params for textbox это один из констукторов вы можете передать туда свои texbox переменные чтобы техт брать сних удобно при заполнении

Comment: он ошибку выводит о том, что не удается найти имя или пространство имен, хотя я изменил на textBox1, textBox2, ...

Comment: В моем коде не чего менять не надо счас покажу как надо добавлять с текстбоксов

Comment: Увы, но ваш код не работает у меня